# How to compare Integer and Double wrapper?

Tags: java

```
Integer i = 1000;
Double d = 1000.0;

??
```

Is there a way for me to compare the numerical values in these two wrappers **without unwrapping or casting**?

I can't use == or .equals() since they compare the reference equality. 
Neither can I use Integer.compare(i,d) nor i.compareTo(d) since they have different types.

Thank you in advance for answering a newbie question.

edit: changed d.compareTo(i) to i.compareTo(d) since it is a Integer method.

Comment: Why dont you convert integer value to double, Double.parse or valueOf. Since you cannot compare or check the equality of two different incompatible objects

Comment: @VivekSwansi there isn't a method I can use to check the contents of two different number wrapper types at all? something like how arrays contents can be checked using the Arrays.equals()?

Comment: There is a built in function of   `java.lang.Double.equals()` .  The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a Double object that contains the same double value as this object.Thus you can't use it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare(double,%20double)

you can use `Double.compare(param1, param2)`

```java
Integer a = 1000;
Double b = 1000.0;
System.out.println(Double.compare(a, b) == 0);
```

As informed by @Andy this is the actual flow

Integer will be unboxed to int, and then widened to double. There is no conversion from Integer to Double here.

Comment: Nit: `Integer` will be unboxed to `int`, and then widened to `double`. There is no conversion from `Integer` to `Double` here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
Double.compare(val1,val2)==0
```

if any parameter are not floating point variable, they will be promoted to floating point.

In floating point operation/comparisons, if one argument is floating/double then other one being int is also promoted to the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this but I am not sure it is what you want

```
d.intValue()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use String:

```
boolean result = ("" + i).equals(("" + d).split("\\.")[0]);
```

Comment: Interesting. So we parse it into String, discard the .0 from the String representation of Double, and compare the String contents.

Comment: Did you try this? It never works, although two simple modifications do work IF d's value is an exact integer (which excludes nonfinites) with magnitude < 10^7.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 No I didn't actually. I am not familiar with String API aside from the usual methods. I thought it would because of how String concatenation works. In any case this isn't the approach I was looking for.

Comment: @REN Yes, we parse value into String and discard all numbers after dot (with dot).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Did you try this? This works with provided values. I do not know why asker need to resolve this issue, but I suggested variant. Yes it not works with all Double diapason, but `Double.compare(Double a, Double b)` also  do not suitable for question conditions, since when we pass integer parameter into function - it casted automatically into Double. So this resolving 1) can be accepting, 2) Provides one more means

Comment: with regex of `"\\."` or `"[.]"` it works, but with plain `"."` it does not work, and that's what was in the Q at the time I commented